stain on ceiling around the edges of ceiling texture
Noticed these stains along the edges of ceiling texture. Theres attic above this ceiling and this room is close to kitchen. Is this water damage? Able to clean with soapy water.
https://imgur.com/a/OASUjy5

This is water damage. Since the stain follows the wall, I would check for things like plumbing vent stacks that are hidden in the wall that extend through the attic to the outside. If this is the case, I would also inspect the roof to see if there is damage in the vicinity.

Thanks for the response. There was a shingle missing in the roof which was fixed. There is no vent stack thats directly under this ceiling. I should also mention that these stains are present along the ceiling texture edge for the entire room. My doubt is if its water damage why its not showing in ceiling texture?

Inspect the attic to see how the joists run. Confirm that the area affected by the missing shingle also affected how water moved along the underside of the roof once it entered the house.
